# Simple Hibernate configuration

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

Content is not allowed in trailling section. I copied declaration from a site and I used the model do apply on my own database

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/HibernateMappingDTD3.0//EN""http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.model.User" table="users">
        <id column="ID_USER" name="id_user" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <property column="ID_EMPL" name="id_empl" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <property column="USERNAME" name="username" type="java.lang.String"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, this is fine:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.model.User" table="users">
    <id column="ID_USER" name="id_user" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <property column="ID_EMPL" name="id_empl" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <property column="USERNAME" name="username" type="java.lang.String"/>
</class>
```